# Error with serial_port_flutter for android> = 8.0

Tags: flutter, dart, port

I am using the example of the plugin to connect with serial ports in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/serial_port_flutter you can download the code from here https://github.com/BbsonLin/serial_port_flutter
The example works correctly for me on physical devices with android less than 8, but when I run the program on a device with android >= 8.0 I cannot get the list of connected devices (in the device menu).
I get the following error:

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/tty/drivers (Permission denied)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqK8b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by rooting the phone and flashing it